# Retrieving a Date value from a GridView in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, casting

I am trying to retrieve a value from a GridView and save it as a Date variable, using the following code:

```
Dim invoice_date As Date = Convert.ToDateTime((TryCast(row.Cells(2).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text)
```

I am getting an error:

> System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox) returned Nothing.

From what I have read, if the TryCast fails, it will return a value of nothing.

I have a similar command for an Integer, which works fine on another column.

```
Dim order_value As Integer = Convert.ToInt32((TryCast(row.Cells(3).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text)
```

Can somebody please help with the correct syntax to work with a Date value?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that `TryCast` returns `Nothing` if it cannot cast to the target type. So, the problem that you have is most likely that `row.Cells(2).Controls(0)` is not a `TextBox`. To debug this, split the line:

```
Dim invoice_date As Date = Convert.ToDateTime((TryCast(row.Cells(2).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text)
```

like this:

```
Dim textbox As TextBox = TryCast(row.Cells(2).Controls(0), TextBox)
Dim invoice_date As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(textbox.Text)
```

and look at the value of `textbox`.

Comment: @user3580480 - Were you able to find what `row.Cells(2).Controls(0)` is?

Answer (score 0):

Try and use DirectCast() and see if that works.